# Maven is not generating .war file

Tags: xml, maven, jenkins

I am using Jenkins for building maven project.

I have tow projects. `Project_1` and `project_2`. for building both project together I have created parent `pom.xml` file. here is parent `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sam.batch</groupId>
  <artifactId>Parent_pom</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>My Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>

  <!--<url>http://maven.apache.org</url> -->

  <modules>
    <module>project_1</module>
    <module>project_2</module>
  </modules>

 <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>my-snapshots</id>
        <name>Internal Repository</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>


    </snapshotRepository>

    <repository>
        <id>my-releases</id>
        <name>Internal Repository</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        <!--url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url-->
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

</project>
```

Here is `project_1` `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sam</groupId>
    <artifactId>project_1</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <!-- <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url> -->
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
            <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
            <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>project_1</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>target/generated-sources/axis2/wsdl2code/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>target/generated-sources/xmlbeans/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>         
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is `project_2` `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sam.batch</groupId>
  <artifactId>project_2</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>


  <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>wstx-asl</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
            <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>com.javaetmoi.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaetmoi-spring4-vfs2-support</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>






    </dependencies>


   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <resource>
                <directory>target/generated-sources/axis2/wsdl2code/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>target/generated-sources/xmlbeans/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java/com/globalss/dnb/monitor/model/</directory>
                <targetPath>com/globalss/dnb/monitor/model/</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.hbm.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

  </build>
</project>
```

When I build these two project without using parent `pom.xml` I get both the project war file.

But When I am using parent `pom.xml` I don't get war files, though the projects get successfully build. But I don't see any war files.

This is the log from Jenkins

```
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-23T03:02:44+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/176M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project_1_Jenkins/workspace/project_1/pom.xml to com.sam/Project_1/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Project_1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project_1_Jenkins/workspace/test/pom.xml to com.sam.batch/project_2/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/project_2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project_1_Jenkins/workspace/pom.xml to com.sam.batch/Parent_pom/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Parent_pom-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Just a hint (it doesn't address your issue): Your `Parent_pom` is NOT a _parent_ POM (there are no `<parent>` declarations in the submodules). It's just an _aggregator_ (see [Inheritance v. Aggregation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance_v) and [Multi-module vs. Inheritance](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit)). If you actually declare it as parent in `project_1` and `project_2` you could move the dependencies they have in common to the then "real" `Parent_pom`.

Comment: Addition: Consider using [Dependency Management](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Management), as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have no parent specified in project 1 and project 2.

So the configuration in your parent pom is not used when you build project 1 or project 2 alone, maven just does not know a parent exists.

This might explain why you get different results if building through the parent or building alone

So add the `<parent>` tag in the submodule poms, pointing to the parent.
It may happen, that than your submodule builds break always. If this is the case, than its caused by something in the parent pom. Remove plugin and resource tags from there until the build succeeds again.

You are also using 2 different versions in the three projects, that's at least unusual. Better use the same version throughout a multimodule project.